# How to put an image file to input[file] from database using php

Tags: php, database, image, input, retain

How should I put an image into `<input type="file">` where the image is from my database(actually, the image name only written into database, and the image store in my folder), just like a `value=""` in the other input type, but `<input type="file" value="<?php echo $imagefileerwerewr; ?>">` doesn't work to retain the image file.

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: use <input type="image"  src="" />

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: I need to put the file in the input file, just for getting update.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way that you can just put you image inside an `file` input and you can update image. I would suggest you that you use both `img` tag and `input` tag to archieve this. You can use `img` tag to show the current image and also you can use `input` to let the users to update another image if they want.

I would suggest you to use [dropzone](https://www.dropzonejs.com/) it has some great features and would be easier for you to manage all this

Comment: I just need to retain it to the img input file, because I about to update an image